# Webbrowser doesn't open default browser in Python 3.4

Tags: python-3.x, python-webbrowser

I'm currently trying to implement a search function into my application that will open into the users default browser, and so far webbrowser has worked for specific links.

When I run this line, it opens Internet Explorer, instead of my default browser, Google Chrome. Can anyone explain why?

```
elif 'google' in user_input or 'search' in user_input:
    if 'google' in user_input:
        search = re.sub('google', '', user_input, 1)
    elif 'search' in user_input:
        search = re.sub('search', '', user_input, 1)
    webbrowser.open_new_tab(search)
```

Comment: Why are you checking  `'google' in user_input:` and  `'search' in user_input` twice?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yeah, I thought about why I was doing that too. I'm not sure why. I just felt like it. :P